# getCurrentPosition not called

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to center the users current location on a map.

But I have a hard time figuring out why `getCurrentPosition` is just skipped. When i debug it just skip the line.

What am i doing wrong?

```
initMap: function() {
    var latLng;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function(position) {
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
            }, function() {
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4, -122.1)
            }, {
                timeout: 10000
            }
        );
    };

    var mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    this.oMap = new google.maps.Map(this.getView().byId("map_canvas").getDomRef(), mapOptions);
    this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        draggable: true,
        map: this.oMap,
        suppressMarkers: true
    });

    this.createCurrentLocationMarker();
    this.loadDataFromModel();
}
```

Comment: Maybe `navigator.geolocation` is undefined on your browser?

Comment: Hm, ' if (navigator.geolocation)' is called fine and I get to ' navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition'. If 'navigator' is undefined then i should not get to ' navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition'.

Comment: If `navigator.geolocation` is null, it would skip the next code. What is `navigator.geolocation`?

Comment: @Henrik, if you get to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`, why do you say *it just skip the line*?

Comment: Or is the fact that `getCurrentPosition()` may return asynchronously, so when `latLng` is used to initialize `mapOptions`, it may not be set yet?

Comment: @Frédéric, When i debug i can step down to ' navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition' without any problems, but when i expect to step into the function it just jumps over the statement and latLng are still null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frédéric Hamidi, mentioned in the comment, `navigator.geolocation` might be not available in the browser you are testing.

But there are some more things that needs to be done. You cannot access `latlang` before it populated. So, you have to change your code to something like below, even if you are testing in a browser which has `navigator.geolocation`.

```
initMap: function() {
    var latLng;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function(position) {
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                var mapOptions = {
                      center: latLng,
                      zoom: 12,
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                this.oMap = new google.maps.Map(this.getView().byId("map_canvas").getDomRef(), mapOptions);
                this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                     draggable: true,
                     map: this.oMap,
                     suppressMarkers: true
                 });

                 this.createCurrentLocationMarker();
                 this.loadDataFromModel();
            }.bind(this), function() {
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4, -122.1)
            }, {
                timeout: 10000
            }
        );
    }; 
}
```

Now, your code will run after `latlang` is available and also notice `.bind(this)` to make sure, `this` same in the callback.

Comment: Thanks. It was just what i need. Now i just have to figure out how it is working :-)